# Can you strip a part of a value from a cell?

Tags: mysql

I have a lot of entries in a `table`, at a specific `column` that contains *values* such as:

```
VV&Icirc;VV
VEV&Icirc;&Icirc;
&Icirc;&Icirc;EV&Icirc;
&Icirc;&Icirc;EV&Icirc;
```

..and so on.

What I'd like to do is run a `query` that would `update` **that specific column**, on every row, **stripping** **out** the `&`, the `circ` and the `;` it finds - while preserving whatever else is in there.

```
Or just replacing &Icirc; with I while also preserving the other things in there? Whichever is easier. If replacing, then &Icirc; would get replaced with `I`
```

Can/how do you do that in `MySQL`?

I'm currently reading about `LIKE` and `Wildcard` but I'm not seeing how to put a query like that together so far.

Using MySQL, InnoDB table name is *ghix* and column name is *zuff*

Comment: What you want to do with the &, the circ and the ; . Like you want to replace that?

Comment: @RaviKoradia Replace &Icirc; with I in the cell while not touching the rest of the info present in the cell, or strip out & circ and ; entirely while also not touching the rest of the info present in the cell. Whichever is easiest.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @RaviKoradia Yup, just tested it. Thanks for helping out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question properly then you want to replace Î with I, right?
If so then you can run below query to replace all in that column. Here my table name is temp. You can use yours.

```
UPDATE temp SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name, '&Icirc;', '|');
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with REGEXP expression.

UPDATE table name SET columname = columname REGEXP 'regexp'

should do the trick